# Errors/warnings installing visualruby on windows (Ruby 2.3.1)

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, ruby-2.3

Gem install cmd output:

```
F:\temp>gem install visualruby
Fetching: cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32
Fetching: glib2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed glib2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gio2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gio2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: atk-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed atk-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: pango-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pango-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: cairo-gobject-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cairo-gobject-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gdk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gdk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: rsvg2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rsvg2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gtk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gtk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gtksourceview3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gtksourceview3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Fetching: require_all-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed require_all-1.3.3
Fetching: visualruby-3.0.23.gem (100%)
Successfully installed visualruby-3.0.23
Parsing documentation for cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for glib2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for glib2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gio2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gio2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for atk-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for atk-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for pango-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for pango-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for cairo-gobject-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for cairo-gobject-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gdk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gdk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for rsvg2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for rsvg2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gtk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gtk3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gtksourceview3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gtksourceview3-3.0.9-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for require_all-1.3.3
Installing ri documentation for require_all-1.3.3
Parsing documentation for visualruby-3.0.23
Installing ri documentation for visualruby-3.0.23
Done installing documentation for cairo, glib2, gobject-introspection, gio2, atk, pango, gdk_pixbuf2, cairo-gobject, gdk3, rsvg2, gtk3, gtksourceview3, require_all, visualruby after 19 seconds
14 gems installed
```

Attempting to start visualruby produced this:

```
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 302
   GLib-GObject-WARNING **:attempt to override closure->va_marshal (63C488A0) with new marshal (04D05CD0)
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gdk_pixbuf2/pixbuf.rb:115:in `initialize_with_hash': undefined method `initialize_new_from_file' for #<GdkPixbuf::Pixbuf:091249C8 ptr=00000000> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  initialize_new_from_inline
               initialize_new_from_file_utf8
               initialize_new_from_bytes
               initialize_new_from_stream
               initialize_new_from_data
        from...
```

So I opened the file and replaced the call with initialize_new_from_file_utf8. Starting visualruby now brings up the GUI, but also several warnings in the command prompt:

```
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 302
   GLib-GObject-WARNING **:attempt to override closure->va_marshal (63C488A0) with new marshal (05CE5CD0)
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 337
   Gdk-CRITICAL **:gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 337
   Gdk-CRITICAL **:gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 337
   Gdk-CRITICAL **:gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 337
   Gdk-CRITICAL **:gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 564
   Gtk-WARNING **:Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/assets/bullet-symbolic.svg.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 564
   Gtk-WARNING **:Allocating size to GtkBox 049292D8 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 114
   Gtk-WARNING **:Allocating size to GtkToolButton 094D1390 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 114
   Gtk-WARNING **:Allocating size to GtkToolButton 094D15E0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
F:/projects/static/tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 114
   Gtk-WARNING **:Allocating size to GtkToolButton 094D1A80 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
```

The provided demo runs fine, but this has me a little worried. I have no other versions of the required gems installed. How do I fix my vr installation?

Edit: The example program itself runs fine, glade does not

[image]

Comment: Hey there. I followed the instructions here: http://visualruby.net/file.Download.html  for Windows. I originally had Ruby 2.21 from RailsInstaller, so I got uru to manage my rubies and installed Ruby 2.3 has requested by the visual ruby page. I have NOT removed Ruby 2.21 as they suggested, and I'm running into the same exact error message. `
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.9-x64-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 302
   GLib-GObject-WARNING **:attempt to override closure->va_marshal (0000000063A48970) with new marshal...` when I do `vr`

Comment: @KaMok That's a warning, not an error. And you fix it by upgrading Glib, where the conditions that caused that warning have now been fixed. And it was just a warning: you could continue using your program anyway.